How does one prevent closure of a question due to personal reasons rather than the content?
Both me and @Dcleve and @Annika have noticed that questions are being closed based on arbitrary criteria. This has happened multiple times at this point, some of the questions having many upvotes and seeming perfectly legitimate such as this one posted by me and mentioned by @causative: If the hard problem of consciousness is unanswerable, is it a hard problem or just a bad question?. A question like this does not seem any more opinion based than many of the other current questions on the front page with 0 close votes.
See also the contents and comments of this question where people point out the problem (this one was eventually re opened thankfully due to those comments addressing the issue, but would it have without)?
@user80226 also keeps continuously updating a question here that was closed already, and now locked, and where the moderators already pointed out that complaints should not be made publicly, in an effort to boost the post, which can obviously induce others to brigade downvote.
How is this not an obvious violation of targeted harassment, and how does one prevent closure due to potential personal dislike rather than the content of the question?

What does the first half of the question to do with the second half, exactly?

@PhilipKlöcking because harassment can obviously induce others to brigade down vote, even if it’s not for a good reason. At the very least the harasser himself can downvote every single time without regard to the actual question. Finally, this effect became more prevalent right after @user80226’s post. As mentioned in a comment on the other post, “ They can just downvote / close vote / flag-bomb someone's posts, which is an inappropriate way to "punish" a user (especially if they're innocent), and it's not unlikely to happen in response to Meta posts (related: "meta effect")”

Nevertheless, I just made edits to this question to make the second half more of a related note rather than imply it’s the only reason for the first

By publicly uttering a suspicion linked to a username you make yourself look no better than the person you accuse.

Edited to clarify I am not the one who posted the "hard problem of consciousness" question.

It does seem like a problem to me @Syed, I agree that your posts seem to get closed very quickly by a certain group of users while similar posts by other users are not closed. I think we should just gather some people willing to reopen these questions.

@PhilipKlöcking what am I supposed to do if a user keeps harassing me in public though? Do nothing? The question wasn’t locked until today, even though multiple commenters on the other post pointed out how it seemed inappropriate for a public forum. Raising awareness can atleast prevent a potential meta effect

@causative " I agree that your posts seem to get closed very quickly by a certain group of users while similar posts by other users are not closed". There are TWO solutions for consistency, not ONE. The other is to also close those similar posts. It is a fallacy to consider the worst non-closed question as the bar to meet. A user asking a single bad question in a year can get away with it, it does not mean we should tolerate 100 bad questions a week for consistency. If that's what you want, then we'd have to be much more eager to also close bad posts by users who ask very rarely.

@tkruse what defines a bad question? Here (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119494/is-it-a-fallacy-to-have-higher-credence-in-things-without-evidence-than-things-w), for example, you incorrectly stated that confidence/credence doesn’t belong in philosophy when an entire section of philosophy (Bayesianism) deals with this very same thing. In other words, what is “bad” or “good” is subjective, and what’s happening is that the opinions of people are being used to rate whether certain other posts are “opinion based questions”.

It's worrying to see a mod state "I think we should just gather some people willing to reopen these questions". If it was "I think we should just gather some people willing to review these questions and consider reopening them" I could understand it, but targeted, user-based reopening is just as bad as targeted down voting, but having it advocated by a mod makes it, in my view, worse.

@JonathanZ I agree with you and in my opinion, the entire problem could have been avoided by the moderators simply following their own rules. For example, the moderators publicly stated that complaints about users should not be made on the meta (since we have a flagging system) but then did nothing about it by keeping those questions open for days and even now allowing them to be visible even if locked. Using my complaints about this to instead then accuse me of doing the same thing (only because I’m forced to due to lack of moderator action) seems to me peak hypocrisy.

@Syed - I agree with you that that meta post was really bad, and should have been shut down firmly and quickly, as it should have been regardless of which user it was directed at. But I don't think that it had as much influence on people voting to close your questions as you seen to think it did. Of course, I have no evidence to support that - I'm just going on vibes here. But I agree with mod Klöcking that you'll make better arguments for yourself if you don't combine the two issues.

@JonathanZ I don’t think it was the main reason either hence why I added it more as a side note, although it definitely played a role given that the close votes and downvotes started to occur more rapidly after that post. If I made separate posts regarding these issues, I think it would have came across worse

As a result the site is now moving 180° opposite to what we voted him for. I (personally) don't like this but don't blame him either because it's become a tug-o-war that he lost

@Syed: "what defines a bad question? " Very simple: a question with either lots of downvotes (bad quality) or lots of close votes (off-topic, wrong place even if good quality). There cannot be any better definition than the reaction of the audience.

Yeah, the Stack Exchange model, for better or worse, is that the users in a community decide what's good/bad, appropriate/inappropriate. To have a mod start handing down their own judgements, and also creating their own faction to enforce those judgements, seems to be stepping beyond the normal bounds of moderator behavior. (Admittedly, that's my evaluation, based solely on my observation of a small number of communities. It's easily possible that that style is moderation is totally permitted, and my understanding is incorrect.)

Perfectly balanced and fair treatment by the community can appear as targeted from a narrow perspective.
Here is a numerical example.
The community decides to close 80% if off-topic question if any asker. Any asker gets 20 out of 100 off-topic questions unclosed, as a courtesy. Those are the first 20 off-topic questions. After those first 20, 80 off-topic questions are closed.
This is perfectly fair, unpersonal, and it gives a bit of leeway to all in the grey zone between on-topic and off-topic.
Now when an asker has exhausted their 20 "free" off-topic questions, the next 80 questions will be closed. At that time, that asker might compare themselves to other askers who are still within their initial 20 "free" off-topic questions.
For consistency, all off-topic questions could be closed. But that would make this site much less welcoming. Having a 20/80 ratio (as an example) is not targeting anyone in particular, it is fair and balanced, yet from a narrow perspective it may look like somebody is targeted. In particular anyone asking plenty of off-topic questions per week, compared to users with a more paced number of questions.
This is of course just an artificial example showing how perfectly fair and equal treatment can appear unfair in particular when comparing users with few questions and users with many questions.
This is not necessarily how anyone behaves on this site, it is just an example.

As you say, it is indeed not how anyone behaves on this site. There is no policy whereby a person is allowed 20 "free" off-topic questions. There is just a group of people disproportionately targeting a particular user. Syed's questions are each fairly normal for the site.

Well, on the math.se there is definitely more leeway given to new posters, but a poorly written-up question from someone who has been around for a while may get comment saying "You've been here three years - you know you're supposed to format your question with LaTeX". I don't know about the specific numbers used in this answer, but expecting better behavior from longer term members seems common and sensible to me.

Syed has been a member for just 35 days, and most of his questions are fine quality. It's not fair to discriminate against a user because you believe them to be another user.

@causative: how do you measure "most of his questions are fine quality" other than by going with the reaction of the audience? It seems your personal judgement is not matching that of other users.

"There is just a group of people disproportionately targeting a particular user." How to prove that this group of people targets a user as opposed to this group being sensitive to bad quality produced mainly by this user? @causative, as a mod, is it your task to decide for this community what questions are satisfying the close votes or not? Why even allow the community to close questions if you don't trust the community?

I have no idea who the other user might be. If I download, or vote to close, it is purely on content. If I have a beef with another user, I will either try to respond civilly to them, or try to ignore them because engaging would be bad for both of us. Unfortunately, the closest we have to automate in the latter is giving the system a list of tags that suggest we should stay clear, and also unfortunately philosophy.se is unlike some of the other stacks in that messages ignored by tag are just grayed out rather than being completely hidden. (Workplace.se has the latter behavior, FWIW.)

One way is to use filters to hide the usernames of everyone on this site. That way, one's votes are completely based on content.

For what it's worth, when I have an "oh, them again" reaction, it is usually on content first, followed by my being curious about whether it is the same few people.
